# Link to the bibliography chapter

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

How to make a reference to the bibiography chapter in the document?

What I need is something like:

```
For information about source please refer to the Bibliography.
```

I want the word "Bibliography" to be a link.

A use the simple

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib/bibtexfolder}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to load the `hyperref` package. Use `\phantomsection` to create an anchor in the document where the bibliography appears, put a `\label` there and use the `\hyperref` command to link the word 'Bibliography' to the location of interest:

```
\documentclass{book}  

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
For information about source please refer to the \hyperref[hellobiblio]{Bibliography}.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\label{hellobiblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib/bibtexfolder}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I changed the document class to `book` and fixed a minor issue with the table of contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jubobs! Your code gave me 2 Bibliographies in the Table of Contens, however I managed to solve the problem - it was as simple as adding the \label{..} line under my bibliography command and the using hyperref to reference it...

Comment: @Makavelli I only get one 'Bibliography' in my toc... Anyway, I'm glad my contribution was helpful. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if you're happy with the result.

Comment: My document is using really lots of different packages and has a pretty complicated structure + uses additional build processing to get the glossary in the table of contents hence probably that's the reason for the 2 bibliographies.